# Gradle Cutom Task Input Property

Tags: gradle

I followed gradle user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html). the following code snippet doesn't produce the same ouput as in the user guide.

```
class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    String greeting = 'hello from GreetingTask'

    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println greeting
    }
}

// Use the default greeting
task hello(type: GreetingTask)

// Customize the greeting
task greeting(type: GreetingTask) {
    greeting = 'greetings from GreetingTask'
}
```

Output of gradle -q hello greeting

```
Line 1: hello from GreetingTask
Line 2: hello from GreetingTask
```

Output of gradle -q greeting

```
Line 1: hello from GreetingTask
```

Line 1 and Lin 2 both outputs are the same. However,
`greeting` task should output `greetings from GreetingTask` according to the user guide but I couldn't get the same result.
my gradle version 6.8.3

I don't know if I did anyting wrong or why my results are not the same?

Answer (score 0):

I was following from the first example like so:

```
class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println 'hello from GreetingTask'
    }
}
```

and forgot the change the string `"println 'hello from GreetingTask"` to `greeting`